# Highcharts CSV File

Tags: csv, highcharts

I have written a program that takes data sent into the server via TCP and puts the data into a .csv file with a time stamp on it. I then want to graph this with something like highcharts to show how the data is changing over time.

The data looks like this in the .csv file

```
14:12 22.5
14:14 21.5
14:16 22.3
```

Its basicly recording the temperature with time and I now want to graph it.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: You should look here : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts uses a timestamps, so you need to convert your time into it, ie. by Date.UTC().

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do with highcharts

here is a line chart example for the same http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/jFj5w/

```
         `data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 144.0],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 176.0]
         ]`
```

here you have to keep the timestamp or the UTC date and the second number will be your temperature recording

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `gnuplot` which is free and easy. Downloadable from [here](http://www.gnuplot.info).

```
gnuplot < plotcommands
```

File: `plotcommands`

```
set title 'Plotted with Gnuplot'
set ylabel 'y-axis'
set xlabel 'time'
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M"
set xrange ["14:00":"14:30"]
plot 'points.txt' using 1:2 
set terminal postscript color landscape dashed enhanced 'Times-Roman'
set output 'file.eps'
set size 1,0.5
replot
```

This assumes your points are in the file `points.txt`.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely, just save your CSV file as `points.txt`. Or change the plot command 5 lines from the end to read `yourfilename.csv` instead of `points.txt`. Either way.